# How to know an html element is modified by javascript(Jquery)?

Tags: jquery

Currently, I am deep into a mess of jquery code. I wonder how can we know a HTML element is changed by javascript(jquery) code?
For instance, I have an html select tag, after document ready the select tag is disable. Because there is a messy of code in my project therefore, I don't know which code or event trigger that change.
I installed an add on name Jquery audit, but it now help in my case.
Does everyone have a solution for that case?

Regards,
Tim Nguyen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Debuging you can use the DevTools of your Browser. In Chromium you can add Breakpoints to DOM-Modifications like this:

[image]

Your code will pause on any modification with a overview of the call-stack and you can inspect the event.

Comment: Thanks Marcus, It's very helpful! <3